# Plotting 3D plane and vectors

Tags: r, plot

I have a plane in 3 dimensions, which I have graphed using the persp function. I also have some three dimensional vectors plotted in 3 dimensions using arrows3D. I would like to have the arrows and plane plotted together.

I have searched for ways to merge plots and to add arrows to plots, but I did not find anything about combining these two types of plots. Below is a MWE to produce a plane and an arrow separately.

```
y <- 1:5
z <- outer(x,y, function(a,b) a+b)
persp(x,y,z)

arrows3D(0,0,0,1,1,1)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set `add=TRUE` in `arrows3D`:

```
x <- y <- 1:5
z <- outer(x, y, function(a,b) a+b)

library(plot3D)
persp(x, y, z, theta=30, phi=30)
arrows3D(x0=1, y0=1, z0=2, x1=5, y1=5, z1=10, phi=30, theta=30, add=T)
```

[image]